# PSR-4 namespace in generated files with Thrift

Tags: php, namespaces, thrift, psr-4

I generate php files with Apache Thrift

```
thrift -out / --gen php:nsglobal=src\\Application\\Package\\Thrift package.thrift
```

The above command generates code in the following path `src/Application/Package/Thrift` and set `src\Application\Package\Thrift` for namespace but I use Psr-4 (with composer) in my project we know src as App so namespace should be `App\Application\Package\Thrift`

my project structure

```
src |
    | Application |
    |             | Package |
    |             |         | Thrift
```

I went generate files in Thrift folder with namespace same as following:

> App\Application\Package\Thrift

Do you have an idea to solve this problem?

I try add `namespace php App.Application.Package` to IDL file and run following command:

```
thrift -out /src --gen php /data/service.thrift
```

But it create extra App folder => src/**App**/Application/Package/Thrift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the namespace in the IDL file:

```
 namespace php Whatever.You.Want
```

Full example can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/tutorial/tutorial.thrift#L70)

Also, remove the nsglobal option and just do

```
thrift -out / --gen php package.thrift
```

> i need App in namespace and src in folder name

If you need the folder being different from what the namespace says, consider writing a shell script (or batch file) to move the generated files to where you need them to be after Thrift code generation.

---

PS: Not sure if specifying a root folder as the output target is such a great idea at all.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But when add this namespace (`namespace php App.Application.Package.Thrift`) to my thrift file and run generate command creates additional folders => `src\Application\Package\Thrift\App\Application\Package\Thrift`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this command but folder App was created. In my project src === App (psr-4 autoloader) i need App in namespace and src in folder name